# Find the smallest number b so that the function $f(x)=x^3+5x^2+bx+1$ is invertable and evaluate $\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(1)$ for that value of b.

Tags: inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

I've seen a similar question asked before, but I still can't figure this out. I got $b=\frac{25}{3}$.

f(x) has an inverse if f is injective i.e. if $\frac{df}{dx} \geq 0$ for all x.

$$3x^2+10x+b \geq 0$$
$$\frac{-10^2 \pm \sqrt{10^2-4(3)(b)}}{(2)(3)} \geq 0$$
$$\sqrt{10^2-4(3)(b)} \le 0$$
$${100-12b} \le 0$$
$$b \le \frac{100}{12}$$
$$b = \frac{25}{3}$$

$f^{-1}(1) = a \Leftrightarrow (1,a)$ lies on $f^{-1}(x) \Leftrightarrow (a,1)$ lies on $f(x)$.

$$\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(1) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(1))}=\frac{1}{f'(a)}=\frac{1}{3a^2+10a+\frac{25}{3}}$$

But this is not an accepted answer because it contains "a", and I get the error: "Forbidden variable or constant: a." So I tried finding a value for a by setting $\frac{d}{dx}(f(a))=1$ but I end up getting two roots that are kind of ugly, and I get the wrong answer when i substitute these in for a in the expression $f^{-1}. Thanks for any answers in advance and sorry for the messy equations I could not get tabular to work (I'm new to latex and it's my first time asking a question here so any feedback appreciated).

Comment: If you have $b$, why can't you just compute $f^{-1}(1)$?

Comment: Your title includes the term ${}+bx$ but then your derivative expression has ${}-b$. Is that a typo?

Comment: I don't follow how you get to the second line of your computation. For $3x^2+10x+b$ to be nonnegative for all $x$, you need the discriminant to be $\leq0$ so that there is at most one zero. (Two zeros would mean the expression takes negative values in between them.) So the second line should be $100-12b\leq0$.

Comment: Where you write $f^{-1}(1)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(1))}$, I think you mean $\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(1)=\ldots$.

Comment: Note that $f(0)=1$, so $f^{-1}(1)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

For what value of $x$ is $f(x)=x^3+5x^2+\frac{25}{3}x+1=1$ ?

Comment: $f(x)=1$ when $x=0$  this means $f^{-1}(1)=0$ so $\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(1)=\frac{1}{\frac{25}{3}}=\frac{3}{25}$ thanks!